# Label number 3 mismatch the shape on axis 1

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

I'm currently trying to create an image classification Android app using a TensorFlow Lite model. When I open the Android App and try to perform classification, I keep getting this error message

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Label number 3 mismatch the shape on axis 1**

Here's the content inside my label file

```
0 A
1 B
2 C
```

And here's the code of my Classifier class:

```
package com.ukzn.signchat;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy;

import org.tensorflow.lite.DataType;
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.FileUtil;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.TensorProcessor;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.ops.NormalizeOp;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ImageProcessor;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.ResizeOp;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.ResizeWithCropOrPadOp;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.Rot90Op;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.label.TensorLabel;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Classifier {

    private Context context;
    Interpreter tflite;
    final String ASSOCIATED_AXIS_LABELS = "labels.txt";
    List<String> associatedAxisLabels = null;

    public Classifier(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        // load labels to a List<String>
        try {
            associatedAxisLabels = FileUtil.loadLabels(context, ASSOCIATED_AXIS_LABELS);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tfliteSupport", "Error reading label file", e);
        }

        // load model to interpreter
        try {
            MappedByteBuffer tfliteModel = FileUtil.loadMappedFile(context, "model.tflite");
            tflite = new Interpreter(tfliteModel);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tfliteSupport", "Error reading model", e);
        }
    }

    public String classify(ImageProxy image) {
        @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
        Image img = image.getImage();
        Bitmap bitmap = Utils.toBitmap(img);
        int rotation = Utils.getImageRotation(image);
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();

        int size = height > width ? width : height;
        ImageProcessor imageProcessor = new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                .add(new ResizeWithCropOrPadOp(size, size))
                .add(new ResizeOp(224, 224, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR)) // changed from 128x128
                .add(new Rot90Op(rotation))
                .build();

        TensorImage tensorImage = new TensorImage(DataType.UINT8);
        tensorImage.load(bitmap);
        tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(tensorImage);
        TensorBuffer probabilityBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 224, 224, 3}, DataType.UINT8);

        if (null != tflite) {
            tflite.run(tensorImage.getBuffer(), probabilityBuffer.getBuffer());
        }

        TensorProcessor probabilityProcessor = new TensorProcessor.Builder().add(new NormalizeOp(0, 255)).build();

        String result = "";
        if (null != associatedAxisLabels) {
            // Map of labels and their corresponding probability
            TensorLabel labels = new TensorLabel(associatedAxisLabels, probabilityProcessor.process(probabilityBuffer));

            // Create a map to access the result based on label
            Map<String, Float> floatMap = labels.getMapWithFloatValue();
            result = Utils.writeResults(floatMap);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The classifier is probably based on the MobileNet label format, which requires that labels start from 1. Since you have 0, 1, 2 & it ignores the 0, it doesn't find the 3.